# Can I transmit a beacon signal from my android device while at the same time scanning nearby beacons?

Tags: android, bluetooth-lowenergy, altbeacon, android-ibeacon, beacon

Is it possible to transmit and receive beacon signals at the same time using an android device acting as a beacon?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Yes, on Android 5+ devices that support beacon transmission (see the list [here](http://altbeacon.github.io/android-beacon-library/beacon-transmitter-devices.html)), you can both send and receive beacon transmissions simultaneously.  You can see a demonstration of this using the [Android Locate app.](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.radiusnetworks.locate&hl=en)  Simply turn on a transmitter, then switch to locating beacons.  If you do this on two Android phones at the same time, they will both see eachother's transmission.

A few things to be aware of:

1. An mobile device will not detect its own transmission.
2. Android 4.3-4.4.x devices can receive beacon transmissions but cannot transmit.  (Some older Android 4.x devices do not have Bluetooth LE and cannot receive at all.)
3. Some Android 5.x+ devices do not have firmware that supports transmission.  Check the list above to make sure your device supports it.

Comment: I'm able to see the results based on your mentioned process. I just have a doubt, how does a device advertise as well as broadcast at the same time? Does the bluetooth chip have a capability of this kind to handle it in parallel ?? @davidgyoung