# Can Android device run Bluetooth LE in peripheral and central modes at the same time?

Tags: android, bluetooth-lowenergy

Is it possible to have Bluetooth LE in an android device running peripheral and central modes for advertising and listening at the same time?

Comment: Yes, and there's already an answer [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/36864215/can-i-transmit-a-beacon-signal-from-my-android-device-while-at-the-same-time-sca).

Answer (score 5):

Yes, you can definitely serve as peripheral and connect to other peripherals at he same time. One limitation to this is the device limitations. Please download **BLE central,Peripheral Checker** app tıo make sure your device supports BLE peripheral, BLE central or classic bluetooth modes.

Although, some blogs suggests that it works with Android ver > 4.3.3, in my experience, we could make it working on Android ver 6.0. According to my knowledge, it should also work on Android ver > 5.0

I used [Immediate Alert Service example](https://github.com/youten/aBeacon) and merged with [Android BLE example](http://www.truiton.com/2015/04/android-bluetooth-low-energy-ble-example/) without any issue. Now I can connect to my smart phone to send data from Smart Discover app (on Google Play), and my device controls to other BLE device.

Comment: can you share the sample app

Comment: I am not working on that project anymore but the example link I gave above should be enough. You can also check the beacon examples available on the net. When I google it know I could find this [link](https://altbeacon.github.io/android-beacon-library/samples.html).

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you definitely can do it.